# using torch.multiprocessing on multiple GPUs

Tags: pytorch, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to run inference on images in parallel using torch multiprocessing.  What's odd is I see only one GPU being used in nvtop and performance is terrible.

```
class Model:
   def __init__(self, nets):
       self._nets = nets or []
       self.to(device or (torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")))

   def set_device(self, ndx):
      #ndx = 'cuda:'+str(ndx) #didnt help
       #os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = str(ndx) #didnt help
      self._nets.to(str(ndx))

   def process_image(self, frame)
     ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = Model(net)
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    pool = mp.Pool(2)
    pool.map(model.set_device, [0,1]) #set GPUs on processed

    pool.starmap(model.process_img,zip(frames))
```

The result is in nvtop I one of the processes on GPU1 with the others on 0.  However GPU 0 is doing all the work.  What is also odd is both GPUs show memory allocated but GPU 0 is twice that of GPU 1.  Any thoughts on what I have wrong here?  Thanks.